What role/right is required to run `Get-AzStorageFileHandle` successfully?
Does anyone know what permission(s) is/are required to use the Get-AzStorageFileHandle cmdlet?
I'm successfully able to query open handles on our file shares, but when I shared the script with a colleague they didn't have access, despite them having the Storage File Data SMB Share Elevanted Contributor and Reader roles assigned (I have Owner, so considerably more).
The documentation doesn't make this clear / there's no mention of any permissions explicitly for handles.
Looking through the storage permissions my best guess is the Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metricDefinitions/read permission, which would be granted via the Storage Account Contributor role;  though as Reader grants access to */read, that should already be covered...

Example of how we're using the above cmdlet for context:
# Before you begin: if you use PIM ensure you've activated the appropriate group/role

# Ensure you have the module installed
# Install-Module Az # https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az

# opens the browser to log your PS session in to Azure.
Login-AzAccount

# ensure you're looking at the subscription your storage account is under
Set-AzContext -Subscription 'MySubscription'

# Specify the resource group and storage account you're interested in
$context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName 'ExampleResourceGroup' -Name 'MyStorageAccount').Context

# Fetch the handles for your fileshare
$handles = Get-AzStorageFileHandle -Context $context -ShareName 'exampleShare' -Recursive

# Show all handles for files/directories
$handles | ? Path | Select ClientIp, Path | ft -AutoSize

All commands are successful until $handles = Get-AzStorageFileHandle -Context $context -ShareName 'exampleShare' -Recursive at which point my colleague gets error:
Get-AzStorageFileHandle : The client 'username@example.com' with object id
'12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-0123456789ab' does not have authorization to perform action


To enable your users to successfully execute Get-AzStorageFileHandle cmdlet youn need to assign them one of the following storage specific built-in roles:

Reader and Data Access
Storage Account Key Operator Service Role

Those roles allow users to perform 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' action which is required to execute cmdlet in question.
You can refer to the official documentation from Microsoft for more details: Azure built-in roles for Storage
When executing any command which gives you permissions related error you should be able to see an action which is denied. For example, if your user has only Reader role, and tries to execute:
$handles = Get-AzStorageFileHandle -Context $context -ShareName 'test-file-share' -Recursive

He will be getting an error saying:
Get-AzStorageFileHandle: The client 'USER_EMAIL' with object id 'GUID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' over scope 'SCOPE' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Knowing denied action, you can search which built-in Azure roles allow it or create a custom role allowing required action if you need to.

The user must have the Storage File Data SMB Share Reader role or equivalent permissions on the Azure Storage account to successfully run Get-AzStorageFileHandle. Read access to file shares and their handles is provided by this role, which is necessary for querying and managing file handle operations.
